# Codeigniter organization chart PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Whats the best way to output a json like an organization chart? Seems my loop is not good. Can't really get whats the empUnd for every employees. How to make a good loop for this type of chart like get every empUnd over and over until its empty

1. Create endpoint that shows the organization structure.
   /test/chart

Response Format:

```
{
    "empNo: "123",
    "name": "Jennifer Sy",
    "jobDesc": "CEO",
    "empUnd: [
        {
            "empNo": "456",
            "name": "Mike Tolomia",
            "jobDesc": "VP",
            "empUnd": [{}]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function chart() {
        $employeeDetails = $this->api_model->fetch_employees();
        foreach ($employeeDetails as $employeeDetail) {
            $test = $this->api_model->checkEmployeeUnder($employeeDetail['employeeNumber']);
            $result[] = [
                'empNo' => $employeeDetail['employeeNumber'],
                'name' => $employeeDetail['firstName'],
                'empUnd' => $test
            ];
        }

        return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($result));
    }
```

My Model:

```
public function fetch_employees() 
    {
        $qry = $this->db->get('employees');
        $result = $qry->result_array();

        return $result;
    }

    public function checkEmployeeUnder($reportsTo) 
    {
        $this->db->select('empNo, CONCAT(firstName, '.' , " ", lastName) AS name');
        $this->db->from('employees');
        $this->db->where('reportsTo', $reportsTo);
        $qry = $this->db->get();
        $result = $qry->result_array();

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: _“Seems my loop is not good”_ - what loop, you have not shown us any. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi sorry, I added my code. Thank you hoping you can help me. THanks guys